# java try catch multiple methods

Tags: exception, try-catch

I am new the java, needing some help.
I need to find which method throws an exception, if any. I can modify catch block ONLY. Can't use StackTrace - I've been suggested to use collections. Thanks for help.

```
public class Xc {
    void canException() throws Exception {
        if (new java.util.Random().nextInt(5) == 0)

    throw new Exception();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Xc z = new Xc();
    try {
    z.canException();
    z.canException();
    z.canException();
    z.canException();
    z.canException();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        //can modify this block only
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use StackTrace?

Comment: to make things harder i believe. Its a homework.